# go get with private gitlab repo

Tags: git, go, gitlab

Despite all the attempts I can't succeed in using "go get" to get a private repo from gitlab
I've tried with .netrc, gitconfig but it doesnt work.
I have a private machine with git on it, suppose it is mymachine.prv

```
git config --global url."git@mymachine.prv:".insteadOf "https://mymachine.prv/"
```

I run this command from a virtual machine with user "gp"
and it keeps asking me the password for gp@mymachine.prv

So I have generated the public key with ssh-keygen and added to gitlab account, but no luck.

Any help please?

Gianpaolo

Comment: Did you add the ssh key for that user to your gitlab account? I am using private repos without any problems with that key set.

Comment: @bserdar: Post says he did...

Comment: @Flimzy Post says he generated a key. Is that the ssh key?

Comment: @bserdar yes, I added the ssh pub key. If I use "git clone" it prompts me for the username and so I can pass username and password of the gitlab user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should helps you. You miss the `ssh://`

Post for example how it works: https://www.scivision.dev/git-pull-https-push-ssh/

```
git config --global url."ssh://git@mymachine.prv/".insteadOf "https://mymachine.prv/"
```

Comment: it says this:
# cd .; git ls-remote https://<machine>/<path>
ssh: Could not resolve hostname http: Temporary failure in name resolution
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Comment: @gianpaolo usually it says if you're add wrong ssh-key https://github.com/jakubroztocil/cloudtunes/issues/23

Comment: @gianpaolo I updated the answer  12mins ago. Maybe you're trying not a final version of answer

Comment: I added a new ssh-key, nothing changed :(

Comment: yes, I used yr edited method. same errors and prompts to enter the password of the user of the local machine (the one where I run the command)

Comment: Thank you.  I also had to switch to a virtual machine in the same subnet, but yor config was necessary too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

When using Personal access token for `.netrc` approach, ensure that the project/repo is in a group that you have access to. Also, the scope of the PAT should have `read_api`, and `read_repository`.