# go get git-codecommit not works in golang

Tags: go, import, aws-codecommit

I'm tried to access the codecommit packages in my project, But getting given below issue. I tired using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53299355/go-get-a-private-repo-from-codecommit) but no use, I don't know how can we resolve it. Thanks in advance

```
go: module git-codecommit.region/repos/util_service.git: git ls-remote -q origin in D:\workArea\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\a7336f14e81412deff871e645affca79a601f7: exit status 128:
        fatal: unable to connect to git-codecommit.region:
        git-codecommit.region[0: 12.34.56.123]: errno=Unknown error


Golang version 1.20
OS: windows
Editor : VSC
Command: go get git-codecommit.region.amazonaws.com/version/repo/util_service.git
```

Comment: go: unrecognized import path "git-codecommit.region/version/repo/util_service": reading https://git-codecommit.region/version/repo/util_service?go-get=1: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/60687391/1369400?

Comment: See https://go.dev/ref/mod#private-module-proxy-direct and https://go.dev/ref/mod#private-module-repo-auth

Comment: Try `go get -v git-codecommit.region.amazonaws.com/version/repo/util_service.git` to get verbose output.

Comment: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
go: module git-codecommit.region/version/repo/util_service.git: git ls-remote -q origin in D:\workArea\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\a7336f14e81412deff871e645affca79a601f7: exit status 128:
        fatal: unable to connect to git-codecommit.region:
        git-codecommit.region[0: 12.34.56.123]: errno=Unknown error

Comment: Can you `git clone` or  `git fetch` this repository on this computer without interactive authentication prompts?

Comment: Yes, I can able to clone it (push and pull also works fine) @ZekeLu

Comment: Does it prompt for username/password when you clone the repository? Have you set the environment variables `GOPRIVATE`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253086/discussion-between-zeke-lu-and-udayakumar).

Comment: @ZekeLu now getting this error when I import codecommit repo in my local-
error while importing git-codecommit.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/util_service.git/files: string literal not terminated

Comment: Hi, I'm in the chat room now.