# go get appears to be ignoring gitconfig

Tags: git, go, gitlab

Looking for a bit of help. I have a private repo hosted on a remote gitlab instance that I SHOULD be able to access. But no matter what I try, `go get` seems to be trying to use https instead of SSH. I can `git clone`, `git fetch`, `etc` without any issue. But as soon as I use `go get`, it fails.

First thing I did was add this:
`git config --global --add url."git@git.mydomain.io:".insteadOf "https://git.mydomain.io/"`

Then I cd to my project directory and run a go get and it fails trying to authenticate over HTTPS with a "fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.my.domain': terminal prompts disabled":

```
PS C:\Users\User\go\src\git.my.domain\ps\wk\collector> go get            
go: downloading git.my.domain/ps/mqtt v0.0.0-20220903204713-6f195510d46e
go: git.my.domain/ps/mqtt@v0.0.0-20220903204713-6f195510d46e: verifying module: git.my.domain/ps/mqtt@v0.0.0-20220903204713-6f195510d46e: reading https://sum.golang.orglookup/git.my.domain/ps/mqtt@v0.0.0-20220903204713-6f195510d46e: 404 Not Found
        server response:
        not found: git.my.domain/ps/mqtt@v0.0.0-20220903204713-6f195510d46e: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/v
cs/3a728c5d3b6137ea441372540f3e7bc1390c001346a70d5b7df3eda6d5e7316d: exit status 128:
                fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.my.domain': terminal prompts disabled
        Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
        If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
go: git.my.domain/ps/mqtt@v0.0.0-20220903204713-6f195510d46e: verifying module: git.my.domain/ps/mqtt@v0.0.0-20220903204713-6f195510d46e: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/git.my.domain/ps/mqtt@v0.0.0-20220903204713-6f195510d46e: 404 Not Found
        server response:
        not found: git.my.domain/ps/mqtt@v0.0.0-20220903204713-6f195510d46e: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/v
cs/3a728c5d3b6137ea441372540f3e7bc1390c001346a70d5b7df3eda6d5e7316d: exit status 128:
                fatal: could not read Username for 'https://git.my.domain': terminal prompts disabled
        Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
        If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
go: module git.my.domain/ps/wk/collector/service: git ls-remote -q origin in C:\Users\User\go\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\7d02e96755cff57eaec3323ab70c24a12ab19
eac805790ed1220d62b15affcf8: exit status 128:
        remote:
        remote: ========================================================================
        remote:
        remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
        remote:
        remote: ========================================================================
        remote:
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
go: module git.my.domain/ps/wk/collector/service/service: git ls-remote -q origin in C:\Users\User\go\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\7d02e96755cff57eaec3323ab70c2
4a12ab19eac805790ed1220d62b15affcf8: exit status 128:
        remote:
        remote: ========================================================================
        remote:
        remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
        remote:
        remote: ========================================================================
        remote:
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
```

I'm going absolutely nuts. I've tried every combination of getting `go get` to use SSH:

```
git config --global --add url."git@git.mydomain.io/".insteadOf "https://git.mydomain.io/"

git config --global --add url."git@git.mydomain.io".insteadOf "https://git.mydomain.io"

git config --global --add url."ssh://git@git.mydomain.io:".insteadOf "https://git.mydomain.io/"
...
```

Is there something special I have to do somewhere? I just don't understand why `go get` is using HTTPS while git commands appear to be correctly using SSH..

======================

EDIT: Ok more expirementing got me to realize that this IS working:

`[url "ssh://git@git.mydomain.io"] insteadOf = https://git.mydomain.io/`

because I get a new error:

```
        ssh: Could not resolve hostname git.mydomain.iops: Name or service not known
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

But as soon as I add that trailing slash to fix it, I get back to HTTPS errors. Is there something going on HTTPS wise that happens before ssh?

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58203258/go-get-with-private-gitlab-repo

Comment: Sadly no.. I've tried with and without the ssh://

Comment: The final URL you *want* is `ssh://git@git@mydomain.io/<remainder>` instead of `https://git.mydomain.io/<remainder>`, which means your first attempt was close, but lacked the `ssh://` in front. Your last attempt had the `ssh://` in front but then had a colon instead of a slash.

Comment: No I mean, I've tried all those options. ssh://, no ssh://, no :, with /, without /, etc.

Comment: Have you tried removing the final slash from the https url : `https://git.mydomain.io` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `~/.gitconfig` file directly, make sure the entry to your private repo looks like this

```
[url "git@gitlab.com:"] insteadOf = https://gitlab.com
```

Maybe something with the syntax.

Also add the url (without `https://`) into your `$GONOPROXY`.